# Obtener la penúltima fila de registro

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hola tengo este Select y quisiera saber como puedo obtener el penúltimo registro que viene a ser el IdSeguimiento_EstadoOT = 13, tengo un script así

```
SELECT TOP 1
    MAX(IdSeguimiento_EstadoOT)
FROM 
    Seguimiento_EstadoOT
```

Pero eso solo me devuelve el último ID

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ``SELECT top 1 * FROM (SELECT top 2 * FROM Tabla WHERE Campo2='somevalue' ORDER by Campo1 DESC) tmp
ORDER BY Campo1 ASC``, lo hallé por ahí, saludos.

Comment: Justo lo acabo de encontrar y también funciono, muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente......

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la penúltima fila:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * From
(SELECT TOP 2 * From Seguimiento_EstadoOT order by IdSeguimiento_EstadoOT DESC) x
order by IdSeguimiento_EstadoOT
```

Comment: Créditos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198962/taking-the-second-last-row-with-only-one-select-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Usted puede ordenar la tabla y seguidamente obtener el número de fila (En teoría el MAX() es el más alto por ende ordenandolos con DESC el max queda en la posición 1 por tanto el 2 es el penúltimo)

```
SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdSeguimiento_EstadoOT DESC) AS ROW FROM Seguimiento_EstadoOT
  ) T WHERE ROW =2
```

Comment: Créditos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159880/select-penultimate-record-with-a-filter